# Simple Batch File Turns "é" into a Different Character

Tags: command-line, batch-file, command-prompt

I have a batch file with a single line in it:

```
src/Filé.txt
```

When I run the batch file (either in the command prompt or by clicking it in Windows Explorer), I get the following:

> C:>src\FilΘ.txt
>
> 'src\FilΘ.txt' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

It turned my `é` into an `Θ`! I've also had it turn into an `8` on another occasion.

The file I'm trying to access does actually exist. Further, if I try it on a simpler file name (`file.txt`) it opens it without any problems. I'm running Windows 7 64 bit. Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: What code page were you using?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to edit the batch file and add the following line to the very top of the file:

`CHCP 65001`

This will set the character set to UTF-8 and should display special characters correctly.